# How to handle textarea in ng-repeat using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array ReqUserDetails with 5 values. I need to show textarea in ng-repeat and write recommendation for them. But problem is, when I write for one textarea it is reflecting others too, since having common ng-model.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ReqUserDetails track by $index">  
  <img class="styImage" src="{{item.image}}">
  <span>{{item.fname}} {{item.lname}} </span>
  <span>{{item.message}}</span>
  <span>{{item.cdate}}</span>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Write Recommendation"
    ng-model="model.textRecommendation"></textarea>                   
  <br>                   

  <button type="button" class="button btn"
    ng-click="writeRecommendation()">Write Recommendation</button>
  <button type="button" class="button btn"
    ng-click="RejectRecommendation(item.puid, item.rid)">Reject</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: change `model.textRecommendation` to `item.textRecommendation`

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your property `textRecommendation` inside the `ReqUserDetails` array object. then bind it like `ng-model="item.textRecommendation"`.

Full code should be like :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ReqUserDetails track by $index">  
  <img class="styImage" src="{{item.image}}">
  <span>{{item.fname}} {{item.lname}} </span>
  <span>{{item.message}}</span>
  <span>{{item.cdate}}</span>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Write Recommendation" ng-model="item.textRecommendation"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="button btn" ng-click="writeRecommendation();" >Write Recommendation</button>
   <button type="button" class="button btn" ng-click="RejectRecommendation(item.puid,item.rid)">Reject</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ReqUserDetails = [
      {
        "image": "image1",
        "fname": "fname1",
        "lname": "lname1",
        "message": "message1",
        "cdate": "cdate1",
        "textRecommendation": "textRecommendation1"
      },
      {
        "image": "image2",
        "fname": "fname2",
        "lname": "lname2",
        "message": "message2",
        "cdate": "cdate2",
        "textRecommendation": "textRecommendation2"      
      },
      {
        "image": "image3",
        "fname": "fname3",
        "lname": "lname3",
        "message": "message3",
        "cdate": "cdate3",
        "textRecommendation": "textRecommendation3"      
      },
      {
        "image": "image4",
        "fname": "fname4",
        "lname": "lname4",
        "message": "message4",
        "cdate": "cdate4",
        "textRecommendation": "textRecommendation4"      
      },
      {
        "image": "image5",
        "fname": "fname5",
        "lname": "lname5",
        "message": "message5",
        "cdate": "cdate5",
        "textRecommendation": "textRecommendation5"
      }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in ReqUserDetails">  
  <img class="styImage" src="{{item.image}}">
  <span>{{item.fname}} {{item.lname}} </span>
  <span>{{item.message}}</span>
  <span>{{item.cdate}}</span>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Write Recommendation"
    ng-model="item.textRecommendation"></textarea>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it is working is correct, model.textRecommendation doesn't belong to your array. So, textRecommendation won't get to know for which array index is it to be updated, wherever it finds the ng-model="model.textRecommendation" it is going to assign the value of that model.

If you need only one textarea to be filled then bind it with that particular array index.

```
var ReqUserDetails = [];
ReqUserDetails.push(image);
ReqUserDetails.push(fname);
ReqUserDetails.push(lname);
ReqUserDetails.push(message);
ReqUserDetails.push(cdate);
ReqUserDetails.push(textRecommendation);
```